# Query existing Hive tavle using PySpark.sql.HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, hivecontext

I want to build query on Hive Table (table name : 'sample') using pyspark sql.
Following is the simple pyspark code I compiled on pyspark shell

```
From pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM sample").collect()
```

Following is the error I have encountered :

```
15/12/04 11:15:20 WARN SparkConf: The configuration key   

'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key 'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead.
15/12/04 11:15:21 INFO HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 0.13.1
15/12/04 11:15:21 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://maprecruit.server1:9083
15/12/04 11:15:21 INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
15/12/04 11:15:23 WARN DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
15/12/04 11:15:23 INFO SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
15/12/04 11:15:23 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: SELECT * FROM sample
15/12/04 11:15:24 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/12/04 11:15:24 INFO HiveContext: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 0.13.1 using Spark classes.
15/12/04 11:15:29 ERROR log: error in initSerDe: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.checkValidity(Table.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1017)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.getTableOption(ClientWrapper.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$class.getTable(ClientInterface.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.getTable(ClientWrapper.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideCatalog$$super$lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:165)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$class.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildrenDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(SQLContext.scala:931)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:755)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 502, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.sql.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe not found)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.checkValidity(Table.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1017)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.getTableOption(ClientWrapper.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$class.getTable(ClientInterface.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.getTable(ClientWrapper.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideCatalog$$super$lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:165)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$class.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildrenDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(SQLContext.scala:931)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:755)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe not found)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:288)
    ... 67 more
```

I know that i'm lost in configuration part. Can anyone help out with configuration part?

PS: I'm using Hortonworks Ambari HDP-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Hive proprietary SerDes typically does not work in Spark (example HBase, ORC).

Give a try with [pyspark-hbase](https://github.com/Huawei-Spark/Spark-SQL-on-HBase/blob/master/README.md)